# C# XML constants

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

In integer.xml, which has the form of

```
<resources>
  <integer name="foo">0x001</integer>
  <integer name="bar">0x002</integer>
</resources>
```

are the stored constants that are needed for both code and xml files.

C# recognizes the Droid.Resource.Integer.foo, but it has some big random value to ID it, not the actual integer i need.
Is there a way to access the int constants by their real value?

Comment: How are you retrieving the value? i.e. What's the code you use to access `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resource.Integer.XXX` is the resource id *of* the entry, to retrieve the value of the id into a variable, use `Resources.GetInteger`:

```
var foo = Resources.GetInteger(Resource.Integer.foo);
var bar = Resources.GetInteger(Resource.Integer.bar);
```

Comment: That works great thanks! Is there a way to access them without a function call? It doesn't sound important, but they are needed within switch, where I can only put constants. If not, I'll use a bunch of if else.